# How to Combine Two Extglob statements in Bash

Tags: bash, copy, glob

Code

```
shopt -s extglob
cp -r !(Backups.backupdb) /home/masi/Documents/
cp -r !(Applications.noindex) /home/masi/Documents/
```

where note that you cannot use forward-flash in the glob environment although TAB-completion gives it to you, as described in the thread [Why extglob except breaking except condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596677/why-extglob-except-breaking-except-condition)

How can you combine the two NOT clauses in extglob?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean "everything except one of the two patterns", you just combine them with a `|`:

```
cp -r !(Backups.backupdb|Applications.noindex) /home/masi/Documents/
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to correct my mistake which was carried forward to your answer. It is wrong to use forward-flash in the glob environment. One thread about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596677/why-extglob-except-breaking-except-condition