# Why extglob except breaking except condition?

Tags: bash, debugging, copy, glob

I run in Debian 8.1, GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) and Lenovo G50-30 with 500 GB SSD and 8 GB flash memory:

```
shopt -s extglob
cp -r !(Backups.backupdb/) /home/masi/Documents/
```

but it will copy also everything from the directory *Backups.backupdb/*, confirmed at the end of copying.

### Messages during the copying process

After 2h copying

```
cp: cannot stat ‘Backups.backupdb/masi\’s MacBook Air/2015-06-25-233115/Macintosh HD/System/Library/Image Capture/Automatic Tasks/MakePDF.app/Contents/Resources/ko.lproj/3x5로 자르기.mkpdf’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘Backups.backupdb/masi\’s MacBook Air/2015-06-25-233115/Macintosh HD/System/Library/Image Capture/Automatic Tasks/MakePDF.app/Contents/Resources/ko.lproj/3x5에 맞추기.mkpdf’: No such file or directory
...
cp: cannot stat ‘Camera Uploads/2015-06-29 11.51.36.jpg’: Invalid argument
cp: cannot stat ‘Camera Uploads/2015-06-29 11.51.53.jpg’: Invalid argument
cp: cannot stat ‘Camera Uploads/Icon\r’: Invalid argument
cp: cannot stat ‘Cancer’: Invalid argument
cp: cannot stat ‘cardio bad/atria-en-ventrikels.swf’: Invalid argument
cp: cannot stat ‘cardio bad/extreme_90_180.swf’: Invalid argument
cp: cannot stat ‘Cardio databases tools’: Invalid argument
cp: cannot stat ‘Cardiology’: Invalid argument
...
```

where I keep unexpected browsing through the backup folder. 
The challenge here is that the Backups.backupdb is several TBs and seeing that it goes browsing it does not feel good.

### No symbolic links

I run

```
ls -lR /media/masi/eb807ed8-7f45-35f8-a345-9da6692b228a/ |grep Backup
```

getting

```
ls: cannot access /media/masi/eb807ed8-7f45-35f8-a345-9da6692b228a/Cancer: Invalid argument
ls: cannot access /media/masi/eb807ed8-7f45-35f8-a345-9da6692b228a/Cardio databases tools: Invalid argument
ls: cannot access /media/masi/eb807ed8-7f45-35f8-a345-9da6692b228a/Cardiology: Invalid argument
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root          7 Jul  8 20:25 Backups.backupdb
ls: cannot open directory /media/masi/eb807ed8-7f45-35f8-a345-9da6692b228a/animations/Embryology/e17_files: Permission denied
^C
```

so the directory is not a symlink. 
Why is extglob except condition broken here by browsing the folder?

Comment: Time Machine may have run and purged the old backup while `cp` was running.

Comment: I'm surprised this does anything at all. On my system, `!(dir/)` does not match anything (unlike `!(dir)`)

Comment: @Masi: is `Backups.backupdb` a symlink? I am asking because `/` and the end of path to symlink matters. Still, as said above, `!(dir/)` does not work on my `Bash 4.2.37`. Your `Bash` is however very new, they might have added new bugs ;)

Comment: @Masi: ok, can you compile and run an older version of `Bash` and check it still behaves like this? It would be worth reading `Bash` changelog.

Comment: @Masi From your update, the `ls -lR` is returning errors even though no extglob is used.   Since the problem exists even without extglob, it might help if you updated the question's title.

Comment: @thatotherguy Curious.  On my system, `!(dir/)` matches all files in the current directory _including_ directory `dir` while `!(dir)` matches all files in the current directory except directory `dir`.

Comment: @Masi What is the issue you're seeing that you didn't expect? Is it that `Backups.backupdb` is included in the copy when you expected it not to, or is it that you get all these `Invalid argument` errors in various directories?

Comment: @thatotherguy I keep unexpected the browsing through `Backups.backupdb` when I said except it. `Invalid argument` errors are the task of another thread, most probably because of filesystem difference between OSX and Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the backslash (I am adding echo for test purposes):

```
shopt -s extglob
echo cp -r !(Backups.backupdb) /home/masi/Documents/
```

It works in my environment (GNU bash, version 4.3.30, OS X)

Comment: I get the same behavior on Bash 4.2.37 on Debian 7

Comment: The same behavior as Mario, so it's not OSX specific.